# Pixelwise 2D Radiometric Calibration

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, camera-calibration

I have 3 images, with an applyied mean filter. 
I0 beeing just the noise image, taken with the cap on.
I20 taken an image which only shows a 20% reflectance target
I90 an image showing only a 90% reflectance target for each pixel.

So rather than looping over each pixel and using polynomial fit (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Where X = [I0(i), I20(i), I90(i)] and Y=[0,0.2,0.9] 
and then applying the polyfit to get the parameters for each pixel,
is there a way to feed a X(i,3) and Y(i,3) into polyfit or something similar to get the same result but faster?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to vectorize polyfit then yes, this can be done but requires rewriting `np.polyfit` manually. Fortunately, it can be built on top of [`np.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) and the polynomial [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) provided by [`np.vander`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vander.html). All in all, the routine looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np

def fit_many(x, y, order=2):
    '''
        arguments:
            x: [N]
            y: [N x S]

        where:
            N - # of measurements per pixel
            S - # pixels

        returns [`order` x S]
    '''

    A = np.vander(x, N=order)
    return np.linalg.lstsq(A, y, rcond=None)[0]
```

And can be used like below

```
# measurement x values. I suppose those are your reflectances?
x = np.array([0, 1, 2])

y = np.array([ # a row per pixel
    [-1, 0.2, 0.9],
    [-.9, 0.1, 1.2],
]).T


params = fit_many(x, y)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

poly1 = np.poly1d(params[:, 0])
poly2 = np.poly1d(params[:, 1])

plt.plot(x, y[:, 0], 'bo')
plt.plot(x, poly1(x), 'b-')
plt.plot(x, y[:, 1], 'ro')
plt.plot(x, poly2(x), 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Keep in mind `np.linalg.lstsq` doesn't allow for dimensions higher than two, so you will have to reshape your 2d image into flattened versions, fit and convert back.

Comment: Great thanks. I will give it a try next week. A vectorized solution is what I was looking for. Flattening the image is not a problem at all.